# Friend authentication empty param

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring, hiccup

I am trying to implement friend authentication on my web app but when i try to login i get this */login?&login_failed=Y&username=*...my param is empty and i cant login,what am i doing wrong?

these are my routes...

```
(defroutes routes

(GET "/" [] (index))
(GET "/indexMessage" [] (indexMessage))
(GET "/login" req (index))

(POST "/insert-user" {params :params}
   (let [firstname (get params "firstname")
         lastname (get params "lastname")
         email (get params "email")
         password (get params "password")
         sex (get params "sex")
         year (get params "year")
         month (get params "month")
         day (get params "day")]
     (def date (str year"-"month"-"day))
     (insert-user firstname lastname email password sex date)))

(route/resources "/public")
(route/not-found "Page not found")
)
```

i used all the middleware needed...

```
(def page (handler/site
        (friend/authenticate
          routes
          {:allow-anon? true
           :login-uri "/login"
           :default-landing-uri "/"
           :unauthorized-handler #(-> (html5 [:h2 "You do not have sufficient privileges to access " (:uri %)])
                                    resp/response
                                    (resp/status 401))
           :credential-fn #(creds/bcrypt-credential-fn @users %)
           :workflows [(workflows/interactive-form)]})
           (wrap-keyword-params routes)
           (wrap-nested-params routes)
           (wrap-params routes)
           (wrap-session routes)


        ))
```

and this is how i start up my jetty server...

```
(defn -main []
(run-jetty page {:port 8080 :join? false}))
```

users is a map like this...

```
 {"username" {:username "username" :password "password"}}
```

is :roles a must in the map?maybe it's because of that?

Comment: That may be unrelated, but the code for your `/insert_user` route contains a `def` statement, which is bad practice because it defines a symbol (`date`) at the toplevel of your namespace the first time it's executed, and redefines it every time you try to access that route. From what I see, `date` is only used in a local context, and so should instead be another line in your `let` initialization vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty new to Friend as well but from the Friend source code I can say that the parameters name of your  POST request matters. I guess you are following this example, if not, it's the best hint you can get actually. Notice the name of the form fields

https://github.com/cemerick/friend-demo/blob/master/src/clj/cemerick/friend_demo/interactive_form.clj#L22-l24

All credential functions take a single argument, a map containing the available credentials, so 
 as there is no explicit POST  "/login" route, the Friend midleware is catching and using them as credentials for your credential-fn as shown here https://github.com/cemerick/friend/blob/master/src/cemerick/friend/workflows.clj#L76-78

So "username" and "password" should be the names of the parameters POSTed to the :login-uri

For newcomers that example is runnable here http://friend-demo.herokuapp.com/interactive-form/

Comment: i have been busting my head over this for two days and now i see that i forgot to put :name in my login form...what a stupid mistake...but anyways,thanks a lot man!